# ASP.net downloading a file fails on subsequent calls

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, download

I am having a weird situation. I have a grid with Linkbuttons.  code is below

```
 <asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClick="DownloadPDF" Text=<%# Eval("Number")%> CommandArgument= <%# Eval("ID")%> > <%# Eval("ID")%> </asp:LinkButton>


    protected void DownloadPDF(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int ID= Convert.ToInt32(((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument);
        string Number= ((LinkButton)sender).Text;

        var pdf = WS.GetPdf(ID);


        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename=ID_{0}.pdf", Number));
        Response.OutputStream.Write(pdf.Content, 0, pdf.Content.Length);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

Click on the first time works ok(downloads the file), next time keep getting error which says "The page you are trying to visit has expired"

Comment: Seems like caching to me!

Comment: clear the cache and tried. no luck though.